# How to get starting and ending time of each download?

Tags: android

I am implementing one application related to downloads.

Based upon my requirement I want to get start and ending time each downloads.

For example the user downloads a app from android market after installing my app, then i need to get starting and ending time related to that download.

If any one know the solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put direct link for download. Just put a php file which gets the address of file and let the user download it. In that case you can easily get the time with php. For the finish time it is not in your access but the best way is to use javascript on page which sends report of download to you via AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to display the `start download time` and the `end download time` the solution that comes to my mind is of using  a `AsyncTask` where the start time can be displayed within the `onPreExecute()`, perform the download of app operation in `doInBackground()` and when the download finishes the time can be displayed in the `onPostExecute()`. HTH.